# Apache server listening on UDP ports

Tags: udp, apache2

I'm wondering how to get Apache listening on TCP and UDP ports. I've found an option through Apache CXF framework but it seems to be quite complex (Web-Services, XML, etc.). 
   All I need is a simple HTTP server with one or two simple web pages answering requests on TCP or UDP ports. Any idea/direction?

With best regards,
Hermes.